# How do I turn off the international keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

I set my keyboard to English (United States) - United States-International. How do I turn it off? I no longer need to type things like é by typing 'e and its

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using Windows 7, open the Start Menu, type "change keyboards" and the first result should say "Change keyboards or other input methods". Click on that. The click "Change keyboards", and reset your keyboard to the regular US keyboard.